# No connectivity between nodes when assigning the Atheros card to different channel except channel 1

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am working on wireless mesh network consist of Linux based desktop machines equipped with Wistron DNMA-92 WLAN 802.11n mini‐PCI wireless adapter (Atheros AR922X).

The wireless adapter supports the "ath9k" driver by default. When I test the connectivity of this driver and I want to switch from channel 1 which is the default one for this adapter to another channel, I got "host unreachable"  eventhough there is a connectivity between all the nodes assigned to channel 1.

Do you have any idea if the driver/wireless adapter suffer from any problems? And Do you recommend me to use the "ath5k" driver for the AR922X adapter since some of the mesh nodes were equipped with AR5212 wireless adapter and I changed them in order to have the same hardware and driver to reduce the probability of having different problems.

I use the following command to assign the adapter to different channels `iwconfig wlan0 channel 6`.

Answer (score 0):

both types of adapters are used in embedded routers, thus support for access point mode is almost perfect. All clients have to reconnect when you change the channel obviously.... like you tune radio and could have expected previous channel to keep playing...